# App rejected for "Parse error 146" during In App Purchase

Tags: ios, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

my new app was rejected by apple because of "Parse error 146" during In App Purchase.

But when I test my app on my real device, all works perfectly.

I've read that error 146 means that the product identifier is invalid. But all my product Id registered on iTunes Connect are correct.

All my In App Purchases are in "Waiting for Review" status. Could be this the problem? Do I have to wait the review of In App Purchase and THEN submit the app?

Many thanks in advance,
Nicola